# How can I specify the welcome file which is in a different path in web.xml?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, web, web.xml

This is the structure of my project:

```
...
├── WebContent
├── MetaInf
├── Ressource
|   ├── index.html
├── WEB_INF
|   ├── web.xml
```

Code of web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>jsptest</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list> 
     <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>

   </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I only get an 404 Error.

Answer (score 0):

According to your structure you put your jsp page in Resource folder. Put jsp file under web content insted of Resource

```
├── WebContent
├── MetaInf 
├── WEB_INF
|   ├── web.xml
├── index.html
```